# OutOfMemoryException when open config file

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, configurationmanager

Sometimes on production server I get out of memory exception. It happens rarely, before yesterday it happend at the end of June and at the end of August. Each time I can see this exception got logged 7 times before windows service, on which the application is hosted, stops.
The application is scheduled quartz job. The only thing is that this job loads (CSScript.Load) and compiles cs files from local directory and execute them, but before loading files it tries to get local folder path from configuration settings and gets out of memory exception.

Code executing:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var result = config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
```

Stack trace

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. (C:\Program Files\SoftCo\SoftCo R8 Services\SoftCo.R8.Services.exe.Config) ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Xml.NameTable.Grow()
   at System.Xml.NameTable.AddEntry(String str, Int32 hashCode)
   at System.Xml.NameTable.Add(Char[] key, Int32 start, Int32 len)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.AddAttribute(Int32 endNamePos, Int32 colonPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Skip()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Skip()
   at System.Configuration.XmlUtil.StrictSkipToNextElement(ExceptionAction action)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, OverrideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSectionsRecursive(XmlUtil xmlUtil, String parentConfigKey, Boolean inLocation, String locationSubPath, OverrideModeSetting overrideMode, Boolean skipInChildApps)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ScanSections(XmlUtil xmlUtil)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor(String locationSubPath, Type typeConfigHost, Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String exePath)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationImpl(ConfigurationFileMap fileMap, Boolean isMachine, ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, String exePath, Boolean preLoad)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have enough RAM on your machine?

Comment: It's probably just by chance that the exception occurs on loading of the settings. I'd assume the problem probably lies in the cleanup after compilation and execution of those scripts.

Comment: This is a long running process right? Instead of troubleshooting memory issues, could you instead spin the workload out to a separate process that runs to completion every schedule period, so that there's no risk of creeping memory usage?

Comment: @SergeyMalyutin it's far more likely that you'll get an OOM from a fragmented heap than not having enough RAM. see Eric Lippert's classic [“Out Of Memory” Does Not Refer to Physical Memory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)

Comment: As for those scripts, I thought so, but can't see anything wrong with: `script = (IScriptExecute)CSScript.Load(scriptName, null,
                    GetMapBool(inputMap, "IsDebug")).CreateObject(className);
     return script.Execute(inputMap);`

Comment: The script is probably loaded into the current AppDomain, which prevents it from being unloaded without killing the process. [This article of the CS-Script documentation](http://www.csscript.net/help/script_hosting_guideline_.html) should contain the necessary information (or at least pointers in the right direction) to solve the problem, assuming that's actually the scripting framework you use.

Comment: @Nuffin I think you're on the right tack there. Tess Ferrandez wrote about suspiciously similar behavior with [XmlSerialization](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/02/15/532804.aspx)
and [Compiled xslt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/05/05/net-memory-leak-xslcompiledtransform-and-leaked-dynamic-assemblies.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, @Nuffin, Conrad Frix. That is the framework we use. Will read and dig deeper into it.